# CakePHP 3.x translation behavior: read all translations with "get"

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-3.8

The cookbook describes how to [retrieve all translations for an entity](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/behaviors/translate.html#retrieve-all-translations-for-an-entity), but it's using `find('translations')`. It also discusses how to [retrieve all translations for associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/behaviors/translate.html#retrieving-all-translations-for-associations). I am hoping to blend these, using `get` and the containment functionality, because I'm already reading associated records at the same time.

To load a league, and all associated divisions with their translations, this works:

```
$league = $this->Leagues->get($id, ['contain' => [
    'Divisions' => [
        'queryBuilder' => function (Query $q) {
            return $q->find('translations');
        },
    ],
]]);
```

So far, so good. But I need to load all the translations for the league as well. This works:

```
$league = $this->Leagues->find('translations')->where(['Leagues.id' => $id])->contain([
    'Divisions' => [
        'queryBuilder' => function (Query $q) {
            return $q->find('translations');
        },
    ],
])->first();
```

but it's inconsistent with all my other code for reading a single entity, which always uses `get`. I tried this:

```
$league = $this->Leagues->get($id, ['contain' => [
    'queryBuilder' => function (Query $q) {
        return $q->find('translations');
    },
    'Divisions' => [
        'queryBuilder' => function (Query $q) {
            return $q->find('translations');
        },
    ],
]])->first();
```

but it results in "Error: Cannot use object of type Closure as array" from `EagerLoader::normalized`.

Am I missing something obvious (or not so obvious?), or is this not a supported option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`queryBuilder` is an option for an actual containment, you can't use it as a top level key.

What you are looking for is the `get()` method's `finder` option:

```php
$league = $this->Leagues
    ->get($id, [
        'finder' => 'translations',
        'contain' => [
            'Divisions' => [
                'queryBuilder' => function (Query $q) {
                    return $q->find('translations');
                },
            ],
        ]
    ])
    ->first();
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Database Accesss & Results > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Getting a Single Entity by Primary Key](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#getting-a-single-entity-by-primary-key)**

Comment: So simple! Thanks. I didn't even consider that `get` might have a `finder` option.